# How do I flatten an Array[Future[Seq[T]]]

Tags: scala, playframework

im searching for 2 hours now and don't get any answer to my problem. I want to have only one Seq to return but have an Array of Seq, so now my question is how do i extract the seq out of the array

```
def searchUsers(query: String): Future[Seq[User]] = {
  var queryStrings: Array[String] = query.split(" ")
  var users = ArrayBuffer[User]()
  queryStrings.map(Users.search(_))
}
```

Maybe someone could help me

Cheers

Update:

sorry that my question is not that precisely that it should be. 
My Problem is that i want to have the return value as Future[Seq[User]] and because of the query.split (i have to map it) it is Array[Future[Seq[User]]]

The error is 
Expression of type Array[Future[Seq[User]]] doesn't conform to expected type Future[Seq[User]]

Comment: What does `Users.search` return? And what is the `users` variable for?

Comment: Is your problem that you end up with `Seq[Future[Seq[User]]]` instead of `Future[Seq[User]]`?

Comment: You have to describe your problem more carefully (maybe more generally) if you want people to help you.

Comment: Perhaps changing the input of `query : String` to take `users: List[User]` would be better. What happens if the user inputs `"foobarbippy no users here!"` for the `query` argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to flatten the `Array[Future[Seq[User]]`, we can first use `Future.sequence` to get a `Future[Array[Seq[User]]` and then flatten it to get `Future[Seq[User]]`:

```
Future
 .sequence[Seq[User], Seq](queryStrings.map(Users.search))
 .map(_.flatten)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the `x.toList` in my answer, but posting to show the usage of [Future#traverse](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@traverse[A,B,M[X]<:TraversableOnce[X]](in:M[A])(fn:A=>scala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f[A, B](x: Array[A], f: A => Future[Seq[B]]): Future[Seq[B]] = 
  Future.traverse[A, Seq[B], Seq](x.toList)(f).map(_.flatten)

scala> f( Array(1,2,3), { x: Int => Future.successful(List(x)) } )
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2, 3))
```